# Actualizar columna en base a sí misma (con solo un valor inicial)

Tags: sql, sql-server, update, tsql, transact-sql

Qué tal, les hago llegar esta consulta.

Tengo una tabla a la que debo actualizar una columna en base a los valores de sí misma (teniendo como referencia un valor inicial)

Sea este ejemplo básico:

```
# |producto | fecha      | columna_a  | columna_b
___________________________________________________
1 | AAAA    | 2020-05-08 | 100        | 100
___________________________________________________
2 | AAAA    | 2020-05-09 | 105        | NULL
___________________________________________________
3 | AAAA    | 2020-05-10 | 107        | NULL
___________________________________________________
4 | AAAA    | 2020-05-11 | 110        | NULL
___________________________________________________
```

En este caso, requiero calcular los valores en la columna *columna_b*

La lógica del ajuste sería el promedio geométrico de los valores del día anterior en columna_a y columna_b, lo que es:

`columna_b (t)  = ( ( columna_a (t-1) ) * ( columna_b (t-1) ) ) ^ (0.5)`

Donde 't' es el día a actualizar

Como verán, para actualizar un registro de la *columna_b* requiero el del día anterior.
No sería un problema para el segundo registro, pero a partir del tercero y adelante tengo problemas.
He probando usando el update, pero me he dado cuenta que tendría que hacer iteraciones para poder actualizar todo, lo que sería un problema en una tabla grande.

¿Existe alguna función para poder hacer este tipo de procedimiento? ¿O alguna forma de usar el update en este caso? O quizá alguna otra forma que no consuma muchos recursos al recorrer la tabla.

Gracias de antemano. Estoy en proceso de aprendizaje, me he estancado en este planteamiento.

*Nota: He corregido el planteamiento que puse inicialmente, el cual tenía una fórmula errónea.*

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Según los datos que obtengo, tu formula parece estar mal.

Comment: Qué tal, Luis.
Sí, consulté bien la fórmula que tenía, era errónea. Decidí replantear el ejemplo con una fórmula más sencilla. Espero que la idea principal de la pregunta se entienda ahora. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según como lo veo, tienes varias opciones.

Existe un método llamado "UPDATE Peculiar" que utiliza una sintaxis poco conocida del `UPDATE` y aprovecha que el motor actualiza fila por fila según el orden definido por el índice Clustered. Siempre se seguirá ese orden, así que si no está definido según el orden que se requiera, no va a funcionar. Todo está explicado en [este artículo en inglés](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten), pero las reglas principales son que debemos de bloquear la tabla completa de forma exclusiva, necesitamos que no se ejecute en paralelo, tener el índice clustered correcto, tener una columna ancla y probar, probar y probar.

```
CREATE TABLE #DatosPrueba(
    ID  int,
    producto    varchar(10),
    fecha       date,
    columna_a   decimal (10,0),
    columna_b   decimal (10,0)
);

INSERT INTO #DatosPrueba
VALUES
    ( 1, 'AAAA', '2020-05-08', 100, 100 ),
    ( 2, 'AAAA', '2020-05-09', 102, NULL),
    ( 3, 'AAAA', '2020-05-10', 104, NULL),
    ( 4, 'AAAA', '2020-05-11', 98 , NULL),
    ( 11, 'BBBB', '2020-06-08', 200, 200 ),
    ( 12, 'BBBB', '2020-06-09', 202, NULL),
    ( 13, 'BBBB', '2020-06-10', 204, NULL),
    ( 14, 'BBBB', '2020-06-11', 198 , NULL);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_DatosPrueba ON #DatosPrueba( producto, fecha);

DECLARE @producto varchar(10),
        @col_b decimal(18, 8);

UPDATE dp WITH (TABLOCKX)
SET 
    @col_b = columna_b = CASE WHEN @producto = producto THEN POWER( (columna_a / @col_b ), .5)  ELSE columna_b END,
    @producto = producto
FROM #DatosPrueba dp
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

En caso de que no quieras esa opción porque algunos no la consideran segura, puedes hacer el UPDATE en ciclos por conjuntos. Esto puede actualizar una fila por producto a la vez, lo que puede reducir considerablemente el tiempo que usarías al actualizar una fila a la vez.

```
--Necesitamos una asignación para inicializar @@ROWCOUNT en 1.
SET @col_b = 0;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Producto ORDER BY Fecha) rn
        FROM #DatosPrueba dp
        WHERE columna_b IS NULL
    )
    UPDATE CTE 
        SET columna_b = POWER(dp.columna_a * dp.columna_b , 0.5)
    FROM CTE
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 columna_b, columna_a
                  FROM #DatosPrueba dp
                  WHERE dp.producto = CTE.producto
                  AND columna_b IS NOT NULL
                  ORDER BY fecha DESC) dp
    WHERE CTE.rn = 1;
```

La otra opción es la de actualizar fila por fila. Para mejorar un poco el rendimiento de esto, podemos ponerlo dentro de una sola transacción con las debidas precauciones para no dejarla abierta.

DECLARE @producto   varchar(10),
@fecha      date,
@col_a      decimal(18, 8),
@col_b      decimal(18, 8),
@prod_ant   varchar(10),
@col_a_ant  decimal(18, 8),
@col_b_ant  decimal(18, 8);

```
DECLARE Prods CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT producto,
        fecha, 
        columna_a,
        columna_b
FROM #DatosPrueba
ORDER BY producto, fecha;

OPEN Prods

FETCH NEXT FROM Prods INTO @producto, @fecha, @col_a, @col_b;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    
        IF @producto = @prod_ant
            UPDATE dp SET
                @col_b_ant = columna_b = POWER( (@col_a_ant / @col_b_ant ), .5)
            FROM #DatosPrueba dp
            WHERE producto = @producto
            AND   fecha    = @fecha;
        ELSE
            SET @col_b_ant = @col_b;

        SET @prod_ant  = @producto;
        SET @col_a_ant = @col_a;

        FETCH NEXT FROM Prods INTO @producto, @fecha, @col_a, @col_b;
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;
CLOSE Prods;
DEALLOCATE Prods;
```

Como puedes ver, la complejidad y longitud del código va en aumento, pero lo mejor será que pruebes la que mejor se adapte a tu situación.

Comment: Qué tal Luis, gracias por tu respuesta.
Tengo una duda: Identifico la segunda opción como la más factible, considerando la existencia de varios productos. 
En ese caso, tengo un problema en la asignación del @@ROWCOUNT, siempre obteniendo el "_Must declare the scalar variable "@@rowcount_". ¿Podrías explicarme brevemente cómo podría trabajar esa parte? Entiendo también que esta asignación no dependería del número de productos.
Saludos y Gracias de antemano.

Comment: [@@ROWCOUNT es una variable del sistema](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Si no está disponible, es probable que no estés usando SQL Server o T-SQL.